# Datos se distorsionan al pasar al back por ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenemos una duda, estamos trabajando con ajax.
Los datos se ingresan por el front y al pasarlos al al controlador por ajax, algunas letras y simbolos cambian. Por ejemplo si se ingresa 21/12/98 se envia como 21%2F12%2F98

```js
            frm.submit(function (e) {

                formdata.append("form", frm.serialize());

                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/ActualizarEstado",
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('Submission was successful.');
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('An error occurred.');
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
 [HttpPost]
        public void ActualizarEstado()
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

            var form = Request.Form["form"];
            var myCollection = RRHHLogic.ConvertToDictionarity(form);

            RRHHLogic.ActualizarEstadoCivil(files, myCollection);

        }
```

Comment: Hola!! Sólo te pasa con la fecha, o con otros datos que tengan caracteres intermedios? intenta mostrar con console.log(formdata) el contenido de formdata para saber como se está recibiendo antes de enviarlo a la petición AJAX,

Comment: con todos los caracteres que tengan tildes, la Ñ, y los simbolos:
34sááw/  ---->  34s%C3%A1%C3%A1w%2F

Answer (score 1):

El `contentType` default de `$.ajax` es `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Por esa razón es que está *codificando* caracteres tales como `(, / ? : @ & = + $ #)`.

Si no quieres decodificar los datos en el otro extremo, cambia la codificación a otro valor, por ejemplo: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` o `text/plain`.

Algo como:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ActualizarEstado",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: "text/plain",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Submission was successful.');
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
```

Otra opción es que decodifiques el contenido del lado del servidor.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El .serialize() codifica esos caracteres. Para decodificarlos utiliza HttpUtility.UrlDecode(String) en el controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void ActualizarEstado()
        {

            var forms = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Form["form"]); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trata de usar el método `utf8_decode()` al momento de obtener cada campo de tu formulario en el PHP e intenta eliminando el `contentType:` de tu Ajax.

```
$nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);
```